# Insert _POST data from a form into MYSQL dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with over 100 dynamically named fields, that post to a php file, I want to take all the fields that are posted to the php file which is currently:

```
Array ( [option_page] => plugin_options 
[action] => update 
[_wpnonce] => a51bfc281a 
[_wp_http_referer] =>/wp-admin/options-general.php page=plug.php 
[13939069] => 
[2171] => 
[3600645] =>
[2168] => 
[13937024] => 
[submit] => Save Changes 
[__qca] => P0-1887521465-1334258158937 
[s_vi] => )
```

From this I want to insert the data into a mysql table in the format:

```
id      | option_name     | value
--------------------------------------------
autonum | post data key   | post data value
```

But the issue is I am only intrested in the post data value after: [_wp_http_referer]
but before [submit] so these can be used as reference points.

The part I am stuggling with is:

- how would I get only that part of the post data dynamically?
- How would I get the required array keys and insert it into the
  table    dynamically?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think fetching *between* `$_POST` elements is the right way to tackle this since the order isn't assured to be the same.

Comment: if you NEED to do this this way (i bet you don't) you can create a blacklist of values to ignore since you know the values you don't want and get all other post values sent with the request.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefix all the dynamic form elements with PHP's array notation: `<input type="text" name="custom[Name]" />`. Something like that where you're not sure what `Name` could be. Then, all you have to do is loop over the `$_POST['custom']` array for its elements. `foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) { ... }`

Comment: The thing is the value coming from the name of the form is a category ID which is why it is useful as this will then be used by other files requesting data from the table.

Comment: I agree with Mike B. Arrays are the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mat try this

```
$start = array_search("_wp_http_referer",array_keys($_POST))+1;
$end = array_search("submit",array_keys($_POST))-1;
$newArr=array_slice($_POST, $start, $end);
foreach($newArr as $k=>$v)
{
    // $k is the key name and $v is the value of that key
    //echo $k."=".$v."<br />";  
    $val=mysql_real_escape_string($v);
    $sql="INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (null, ".$k.", ".$val.")";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: this is almost their, instead of keeping the keys the same it renames name them 0,1,2.. is there any way to keep the same value?

Comment: I've tested it on my localhost and it's working, keys are not being renamed.

Comment: sorry that was my issue with using $key instead of $k. One thing I am seeing though is, submit is stilling being included? :S

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{

if($key == "_wp_http_referer")
{
$counter = 1;
}

if($counter == "1")
{
if($key != "submit")
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name(id, option_name, value) VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."')");
}
}

}
```

Comment: @MarcB added mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: Use PDO.. this site is ridden with "Use PDO" messages, it's time to let `mysql_*` die.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$discard_array = array('option_page', 'action', '_wpnonce', '_wp_http_referer', 'submit', '__qca', 's_vi');
$good_array = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    if (!in_array($key, $discard_array)) $good_array[$key] = $val;
}

// use $good_array to insert your data into db
print_r($good_array);
```

Or, if all of the "good" values have always numeric keys, here's a simplified variation:

```
$good_array = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    if (is_numeric($key)) $good_array[$key] = $val;
}
print_r($good_array);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry to sound tottally stupid but how would I complete the rest of it, to say echo all the 'good' values, as it keeps generating errors.

Answer (score 0):

The keys you want seem to be all numeric, so you could only store those. Like others before me, I also suggest using PDO for added security and convenience.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $key) {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table_name(option_name, value) VALUES (?, ?)');
        $stmt->execute(array($key, $value));
    }
}
```